# Does the VideoCapture method of the OpenCV library (in Python) process every frame, or does it also skip frames when doing hefty processing?

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, video-capture

I'm using the OpenCV library in Python to read live videoframes for the purpose of tracking multiple objects in each frame.

I do this using the VideoCapture method, with the code looking something like this:

```
vid = cv2.VideoCapture()

# Loop over all frames
while True:

    ok, frame = vid.read()
    if not ok:
       break

    # Quite heavy computations
```

So i get that every while loop, `VideoCapture` calls the `read()` method to process one frame. However, I was wondering what happens during the processing of this frame? My guess is that a number of frames are skipped during this processing. Is this true or are frames added to a buffer and do they eventually all get processed sequentially?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even though `VideoCapture` has a buffer to store images, in a heavy process your loop **will skip some frames**.  By standard, your `VideoCaptureProperties` has the property `CAP_PROP_BUFFERSIZE = 38`, meaning it will store 38 frames. The [`read()`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d8/dfe/classcv_1_1VideoCapture.html#a473055e77dd7faa4d26d686226b292c1) method uses [`grab()`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d8/dfe/classcv_1_1VideoCapture.html#ae38c2a053d39d6b20c9c649e08ff0146) method that reads the next frame from the buffer.

You can test it yourself, below is a simple example with a time delay to simulate a heavy process.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import time
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while(True):
    # Capture frame-by-frame
    ret, frame = cap.read()

    # Our operations on the frame come here
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    # Display the resulting frame
    cv2.imshow('frame',gray)

    # Introduce a delay to simulate heavy process
    time.sleep(1) 
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

# When everything done, release the capture
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

You will see the image skips frames (and does not create a "slow-motion" effect that we would expect in a slow sequence of images). Therefore, if your process is fast enough, you can match the camera FPS.

Comment: But does this mean that if the process is too computationally heavy, that the actual processing will start to slowly lag behind the camera input? Or is the buffer kept up-to-date, meaning that each while loop, the process grabs one of the most recent camera frames?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're not reading from the file, camera's frames will be added to the buffer of predefined size. You can access this through

```
cv2.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_BUFFERSIZE)
```

and set with

```
cv2.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_BUFFERSIZE, my_size)
```

After the buffer is filled, new frames are skipped.